# Retain user selected text on blur/focus

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, focus, blur, selectedtext

How can I retain the user's text selection when calling `$(inputElement).focus()` on some text input element, `inputElement`, so that they can still use Ctrl+C after inputting some text top their initial selection?

I have considered intercepting the `$(document).blur(...)` event and preventing propagation to keep the selected text, but I'm not sure if it will work across all major browsers, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

if i didn't misunderstood...

you can use `window.storage` or `document.cookie`(in case window.storage is un available)... when the user input text in **the** field you can store its value(onBlur) against an id and on **ctrl+C** retrieve the value and put it else where (in case of *ctrl+z*)

Comment: I already know which text the user selected. I just don't want to jar the user's expectations by automatically de-selecting their selection just because I want them to focus on an input field. They may have wanted to copy the selected text. I have looked at jQuery clipboard plugins, but none of them work reliably across browsers without Flash support.